# Why is this copy constructor called rather than the move constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor

The following code snippet causes the copy constructor to be called where I expected the move constructor to be called:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() { puts("Foo gets built!"); }
    Foo(const Foo& foo) { puts("Foo gets copied!"); }
    Foo(Foo&& foo) { puts("Foo gets moved!"); }
};

struct Bar { Foo foo; };
Bar Meow() { Bar bar; return bar; }
int main() { Bar bar(Meow()); }
```

On VS11 Beta, in debug mode, this prints:

```
Foo gets built!
Foo gets copied!
Foo gets copied!
```

I checked the standard and `Bar` seems to meet all requirements to have a default move constructor automatically generated, yet that doesn't seem to happen unless there's another reason why the object cannot be moved. I've seen a lot of move and copy constructor related questions around here but I don't think anyone has had this specific issue.

Any pointers on what's going on here? Is this standard behaviour?

Comment: Does `return std::move(bar);` change anything? BTW, gcc 4.7.0 calls the move constructor (with copy elision turned off).

Comment: BTW, gcc 4.6.1 doesn't call either the copy or move ctor.

Comment: g++ 4.5.3 only creates the object: "Foo gets built!" (copy elision), while with copy elision disabled it copies the object twice. Isn't a move constructor only called when you have an rvalue? I'm not entirely sure Meow() qualifies.

Comment: If I explicitely declare a move constructor in Bar, it gets called, so this really is an issue with the generation of a default move constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, VS11 doesn't provide a default move constructor.  See [Move Semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the Remarks section - to quote:

> Unlike the default copy constructor, the compiler does not provide a
>   default move constructor.

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! Is that somehow allowed by the standard? If not I guess I'll open a bug on Microsoft Connect, even though they must be well aware of it.

Comment: MS just haven't finished implementing all of the new C++11 features yet.  There's more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx

Comment: Damn, we're not even getting the default move constructor generation for the final VS11 release :/