# Why there is no implicitly generated move constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, move-constructor

Say, I have a class with a movable resource as its member:

```
struct A {
  std::vector<int> v;
};
```

There is an implicitly generated copy constructor, which works perfectly and is implemented roughly like this:

```
// Implicitly generated copy constructor
A(const A& rhs) : v(rhs.v) {};
```

And I expect a move constructor to be implicitly generated the same way in C++11:

```
// Move constructor is not implicitly generated, why?
A(A&& rhs) : v(std::move(rhs.v)) {};
```

However, no move constructor is implicitly generated, at least in Visual Studio 2010. And a vector is copied in the following code:

```
A a;
A b(std::move(a));  // a.v is copied, not moved
```

My question is - why? For my point of view, there is no difference for the compiler to implicitly generate copy of move constructor - it has full information for both of these.

Or maybe move constructor *should* be generated by the standard, but Visual Studio doesn't do this?

**Update**

I debugged the code, and the `vector(const _Myt& _Right)` constructor is called in `<vector>` file. When I write move constructor explicitly, the `vector(_Myt&& _Right)` constructor is called.

**Update2**

Just checked it: the same behavior in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.

**Update3**

Ok, I agree this is a duplicate, but the link provided in the close reason is incorrect. Correct link is provided in the comments: [Why is this copy constructor called rather than the move constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10201659/261217)

And here is why, from [the VC blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx):

> Rvalue references v3.0 adds new rules to automatically generate move
>   constructors and move assignment operators under certain conditions. 
>   This will not be implemented in VC11, which will continue to follow
>   VC10's behavior of never automatically generating move
>   constructors/move assignment operators.  (As with all of the
>   not-yet-implemented features here, this is due to time and resource
>   constraints, and not due to dislike of the features themselves!)

Comment: How are you coming to the conclusion that no move constructor is generating?

Comment: I have a feeling that std::vector does not have trivial constructors, and for that reason implicit move constructors are not generated here. However, I cannot find a reference for this.

Comment: Looks like this is a [known bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991874/why-is-this-code-trying-to-call-the-copy-constructor).

Comment: Another similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201659/why-is-this-copy-constructor-called-rather-than-the-move-constructor?rq=1