# Adding struct items containing a unique_ptr to an stl container

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I had two matching vectors of `unique_ptr`. I decided to unify them by making one vector of structs containing two `unique_ptr` (the struct will also contain other items, eventually, hence this refactoring).

What is the best approach for me to add new items in this vector?

My current code is

```
std::vector<DestinationObjects> destinations;
for (unsigned short &id: ids) {
    DestinationObjects d;

    d.transmitter = unique_ptr<Transmitter> (new Transmitter(id));
    d.controller = unique_ptr<Controller> (new Controller(id));

    destinations.push_back(d);
}
```

Of course this copies `d`, causing issues with `unique_ptr`. What is the best approach to fixing this?

Options I can conceive of, some of which I am not sure will work:

1. Just switch to `shared_ptr`. (A simple find-replace, but feels like a cop-out).
2. Write a move constructor for the struct that moves the unique_ptr. (Another thing to maintain that could go wrong, as I expand the struct).
3. Push back an empty struct instance with null pointers for the unique_ptr and edit these in place once in the vector. (Fiddly syntax. Also I'm not sure this would even work).

Any ideas what would be another approach? Or why I should prefer one of the ones I have listed?

Comment: What issues with `unique_ptr` do you think your code causes?

Comment: The implicit move constructor should be fine, unless you've killed it by writing your own copy constructor for some reason. The type has to be movable anyway, since `vector` needs to move objects when it reallocates.

Comment: Just... move it? Or better, get yourself a constructor like a boss and emplace_back.

Comment: @Oswald: It can't be copied, so `push_back(d)` will fail to compile.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Aha! I think the compiler I'm currently testing with is failing to write an implicit move constructor (VC11). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201659/why-is-this-copy-constructor-called-rather-than-the-move-constructor

Comment: If the lifetime of the objects *in* the struct is supposed to be the same lifetime *of* the struct - and your use of unique_ptr suggests this might be so - then why aren't they just on the stack???

Comment: @user1158692 Mainly because these objects are really quite large and I'm creating a substantial number of them. But I'm willing to acknowledge I may be making a mistake by not putting them on the stack.

Comment: If you are storing them in a vector, then you only have one "on the stack" at any given time (the rest are in the vector whose space is on the heap).  And if you use emplace_back instead of push_back, you won't even have that.

Comment: @user1158692: As a follow-up to your and Nevin's points, I also start several threads with pointers to these objects. If I were to store the objects directly in the vector, I imagine I'd have to restructure my threads to take a pointer to the vector + an index (rather than a pointer to the object), if they were to reliably have access to these objects. Unless there's another trick I'm not aware of?

Comment: @rod does the `vector` change size after you pass them off to the threads and before the threads finish?  If not, their address (in the `vector`) will stay stable.

Answer (score 1):

Simpley do a `vec.emplace_back( std::move(d) )`.

If (as mentioned in your comment) your compiler does not implement implicit move construtors, write your own `move` constructor.  My advice in the future is whenever you have a problem with any C++11 feature and are asking a question, mention that you are using this compiler, as there is a pretty good chance that it's "C++11 support" will be an important issue.

If your compiler does not support any move constructor at all, stop using `unique_ptr` -- they are rather useless without `move` constructors.  ;)